Can I request even less access from the Google API?
I'm implementing Google login using the Google client libraries on both iOS and Android. I need very minimal access: only the ability to write new files to the user's Drive. As such, the only scope I request is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file. However, the login looks like this:

It's telling the user that the app will have access to their personal info and email and be able to associate them to this info. I do not need or want that info/ability, and it looks suspicious for my app to request that, since it does not need it. Is it possible for me to not request that info? Or does every usage of the Google API inherently request that?
A simplified snip of the relevant code in iOS (slightly older calls because I need to support older devices):
 GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = ...
 GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file" ]
 GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()


Please edit your question and include your code

Sorry, I thought I had included the relevant bit already. I added the boilerplate in case that helps.

You are using Sign-In or Google login.
Sign-In is Authentication logging a user in.  By default it adds profile, openid and email scopes.  This is in order for your application to know who the user is that has logged in.  (id_token returned)
Google drive file scope is authorization you are asking a user to authorize your application to access their drive account in order to store files.  (access_token returned sometimes a refresh_token)
So by default the library you are using is adding the extra scopes because you are also signing a user into their google account.

That makes sense, but is there any way to use the Google Drive API without those additional scopes? Presumably I have to authenticate the user before I can use the Google Drive API?

use Oauth2 not SignIn.  How that is done and if its possible depends on the language and the library you are using.

But Google SignIn /is/ the Google-recommended implementation of oauth2 for iOS?

It looks like on Android, there's AuthorizationClient for flows like this, but on iOS, Google seems to say to do what I'm doing. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api-access

You are still not looking at authorization https://developers.google.com/identity/authorization

Isn't what I linked about authorization? It exactly describes what I'm doing. "Some Google services, such as Drive, Gmail, and many others, provide public APIs that you can use to create apps that help users work with their data in these services. To access these services, apps must implement one of the OAuth 2.0 client flows to get consent from users and obtain access tokens, which grant access to the APIs. You can use the Google Sign-In library, which implements the OAuth 2.0 flow for you, to get access tokens for the signed-in user."
